# "10.0" is removed entirely when replacing ".0" with ""

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column that contains strings of floating numbers, and I want to remove the trailing ".0" where applicable. However, when doing `df["numbers"].str.replace(".0", "")`, the string "10.0" is removed entirely, instead of being replaced with "10". This only seems to affect the number 10, 100, etc.

MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"numbers": ["1.0", "10.0", "10.1", "100.0", "100.1", "99.0"]})
print df
#   numbers
# 0     1.0
# 1    10.0
# 2    10.1
# 3   100.0
# 4   100.1
# 5    99.0
print df.numbers.str.replace(".0", "")
# 0      1
# 1
# 2     .1
# 3      0
# 4    0.1
# 5     99
```

Is this a bug or is it working as intended? Also notice that "10.1" is changed to ".1" with this approach, which is weird.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Dataframe.str.replace` takes a regular expression, and thus the `.` is matching any character. You want

```
df.numbers.str.replace("\.0", "")
```

Answer (score 6):

Need `$` for match end of `string`s and escape `.` by `\`:

```
print (df.numbers.str.replace("\.0$", ""))
0        1
1       10
2     10.1
3      100
4    100.1
5       99
Name: numbers, dtype: object
```